# ¿Cómo realizar un buen responsive en Ionic?

Tags: ionic, ionic3, ionic2, ionic-framework, ionic4

Realice una aplicación pero en los dispositivos las imágenes se corren, se que `Ionic` tiene un buen `responsive` pero ¿Qué debo hacer para evitar estos errores? [image: galaxys5] [image: iphone 5se][image: iphone 6][image: iphone6+][image: ipad]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar la grid de ionic para poder hacer buen responsive de tu aplicación, manejando los tamaños de tus imagenes en columnas y los medias queries mediante las clases que vienen integradas en ionic en sus css utilies

[Ion Grid](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/grid)